# Can't mount hard drive. Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, mount

I am trying to recover some pictures on my 320 GB Hard Disk, so I put in a Live Ubuntu CD and am in that right now.

In the devices list, it shows my USB drive, but not my 320 GB Hard Disk. I can see the disk in Disk Utility (it says it's on `/dev/sda`), but it's not mounted, and it says it has a few bad sectors but it is OK.

In Disk Usage Analyzer, it says my maximum capacity is 13.4 GB, so it's definitely not using the 320 GB Hard Disk.

I tried the following:

`sudo mkdir /media/newhd` (worked)

`sudo mount /dev/sda /media/newhd` (didn't work. it says I must specify the filesystem type)

I then tried:

`fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda` (didn't work. Said: Superblock invalid, trying to backup blocks. then: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open `/dev/sda`. The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct `ext2` filesystem. If the device is valid and it contains an `ext2` filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running `e2fsck` with an alternate superblock)

Does anyone have any ideas? The whole problem started when my Windows Vista said "Can't find operating system". Any ideas on how I can get on to my hard drive at `/dev/sda`?

Comment: Try `ls -l /dev/sda*` to get a list of **partitions** on the hard drive.  `mount` and `fsck` reference *filesystems*, which are installed into *partitions*, not entire hard disk drives, e.g. `/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to mount the specific partition as in `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/newhd`.

What does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` output say about the partition table? This will tell you if you have a valid partition table which is questionable since you are reporting only 13GB.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to mbair's answer, have a look at GParted. It will show you the individual partitions, their names, and any errors, all in a much easier form to understand than `fdisk` or its ilk.

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

this will give you list of hard drives select one out of them

```
sudo mount selected drive(/dev/sda1) to /mnt
```

then for un mount use

```
sudo umount /mnt 

or

sudo umount selected drive(/dev/sda1)
```